# How to JOIN tables in many-to-many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table named category which has fields and fields has field options

```
category->fields->fields_options
```

I've created a table cat_fields

```
┏━━━━┳━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ id ┃ cat_id ┃ field_id ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 0  ┃ 1      ┃ 2        ┃
┣━━━━╋━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃ 1  ┃ 1      ┃ 1        ┃
┗━━━━┻━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

Now I need this table to get results from category
so that I can have all the fields related to category and all the options related to the fields of that category.

Is it possible to get all that in one go?

Comment: can you show your table structure?

Comment: Can you provide sample data for all the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show the layout of the other two tables, but presuming each has an ID field, the following should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM `category`
JOIN `fields`
ON `fields`.`field_id` = `category`.`field_id`
JOIN `field_options`
ON `field_options`.`field_id` = `fields`.`field_id`
```

Adjust to use the actual column names and table names.

Comment: had to add one more Join for the table(`category_field` )and it worked as charm.Not the answer i wanted, but gave me an  insight on Joins to find my own answer. So, thanks and marking it as an answer.